# TypeError in Discord.JS-Commando Discord Bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js, commando

Ok, so I have a bot built in `discord.js-commando`. I';ve been doing some tweaking to it, mainly trying to add some more functionality, such as logging commands and such to a channel by name as well as adding console.error logging.

Now my attempts to get channel logging are visible in the commands, however the bot keeps throwing a TypeError.... I have no idea what is causing this error or for that matter how to fix it.

Can someone please take a look at my code and help me figure out what is causing the TypeError?

This is the error I keep getting:

`console.error`

```
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272196+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: this.commands.filterArray is not a function
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272208+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandRegistry.findCommands (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/registry.js:438:41)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272208+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandDispatcher.matchDefault (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/dispatcher.js:254:34)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272209+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandDispatcher.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/dispatcher.js:238:21)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272209+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandDispatcher.handleMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/dispatcher.js:114:18)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272210+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandoClient.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/client.js:68:51)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272210+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272211+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272212+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272213+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
2020-09-30T23:08:24.272213+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
```

Here is my main bot file:

`index.js`

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const path = require('path');
const prefix = (process.env.BOT_PREFIX);
const twitch_url = (process.env.TWITCH_URL);
const embed_color = (process.env.EMBED_COLOR);
const embed_img = (process.env.EMBED_IMG);
const embed_url = (process.env.EMBED_URL);
const avatar_url = (process.env.AVATAR_URL);
const thumbnail_url = (process.env.THUMBNAIL_URL);
const welcome_channel = (process.env.WELCOME_CHANNEL_NAME);
const member_role = (process.env._MEMBER_ROLE_NAME);
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Client({
    commandPrefix: prefix
})

client.registry
    .registerDefaultTypes()
    .registerGroups([
        ['admin', 'Administration'],
        ['mod', 'Moderation'],
        ['fun', 'Fun'],
        ['misc', 'Miscellanious'],
        ['util', 'Utility']

    ])
    .registerDefaultGroups()
    .registerDefaultCommands()
    .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'))

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}(${client.user.id})`)
    client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}help`, {
        type: "STREAMING",
        url: twitch_url
    })
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log(`New User "${member.user.username}" has joined "${member.guild.name}"`);
    guildMember.addRole(guildMember.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === member_role));


    let channel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === welcome_channel);
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Yuzuki Yukari", avatar_url)
        .setUrl(embed_url)
        .setColor(embed_color)
        .setImage(embed_img)
        .setThumbnail(thumbnail_url)
        .setFooter("Yuzuki Yukari", avatar_url)
        .addField("Welcome", `${member.user.username} has joined ${member.guild.name}`)
    return channel.send(embed).catch(console.error);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
    let channel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === welcome_channel);
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Yuzuki Yukari", avatar_url)
        .setUrl(embed_url)
        .setColor(embed_color)
        .setImage(embed_img)
        .setThumbnail(thumbnail_url)
        .setFooter("Yuzuki Yukari", avatar_url)
        .addField("Goodbye", `${member.user.username} has left ${member.guild.name}`)
    return channel.send(embed).catch(console.error);
});

client.on('error', console.error)
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Here is my package.json file:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "yuzuki",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Discord Moderation Bot built using Discord.js commando",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Nimbi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.0.1",
    "discord.js-commando": "^0.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "snekfetch": "^4.0.4",
    "sqlite": "^4.0.14",
    "uws": "^100.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.13.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

My dependencies and their versions can be seen in my `package.json`, however my node.js version is `^12.0.0`, my discord.js version is `^12.0.1`, and my discord.js-commando version is `^0.10.0`  if that helps.

Comment: We dont need this much code to help you solve your issue, this is way over necessary. Anyways make sure your node version is 12 or greater as its the minimum required for djs

Comment: It is, however I have no idea where my issue is coming from so I put what I have in case I missed something somewhere.

Comment: I'm also hosting it on Heroku via git deployment since my VPS took a dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.js-commando@0.10.0` isn't compatible with `discord.js@12`. It's [`package.json`](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/v0.10.0/package.json#L40) specifies that Discord.js **`^11.2.0`** must be used.

The error is because `Collection#filterArray` was removed in v12, and therefore `this.commands.filterArray` is `undefined` and not a function in the Commando code.

You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade to Discord.js v11.
2. Use the `master` branch of `discord.js-commando`, which is compatible with Discord.js v12. However, this branch may be unstable and/or have bugs.
   To use this, change `"discord.js-commando": "^0.10.0"` in your `package.json` to `"discord.js-commando": "discordjs/Commando"`. See [GitHub URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls) in npm's `package.json` documentation for more details on this.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem entirely! =)